# Use Cropit in Meteor js for image cropping before upload via slingshot

Tags: jquery, image, meteor, crop

Is there anyone who has the experience of using cropit with meteor?

I want to crop the images before I send them to S3 via slingshot.

So I install cropit with

`meteor add suxez:jquery-cropit`

and based on cropit's official website, I add

```
 <div class="image-editor">
                    <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">
                    <div class="cropit-preview"></div>
                    <div class="image-size-label">
                        Resize image
                    </div>
                    <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
                    <button class="rotate-ccw">Rotate counterclockwise</button>
                    <button class="rotate-cw">Rotate clockwise</button>

                    <button class="export">Export</button>
                </div>
```

to my template, and

```
Template.XXXXXX.onCreated(function () {
    $('.image-editor').cropit({
        exportZoom: 1.25,
        imageBackground: true,
        imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 20,
        imageState: {
            src: 'http://lorempixel.com/500/400/',
        },
    });
```

to my onCreated funciton,and add

```
'click .rotate-cw': function () {
        $('.image-editor').cropit('rotateCW');
    },
    'click .rotate-ccw': function () {
        $('.image-editor').cropit('rotateCCW');
    },
    'click .export': function () {
        var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
        window.open(imageData);
    },
```

to my template event. and finally

```
.cropit-preview {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
.cropit-preview-image-container {
    cursor: move;
}
.cropit-preview-background {
    opacity: .2;
    cursor: auto;
}
.image-size-label {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
input, .export {
    /* Use relative position to prevent from being covered by image background */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
}
button {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

to my CSS....However, it does not work at all....
I tried upload the image by clicking the upload button,
but there is no preview...and export button doesnt work either.....

Could anyone help me with this please??? :)

Comment: Are there any errors in the console of the browser?

Comment: Not really, there is one error "Failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost:2323/packages/0f7c38a73e1fd696f71cacdd4284e82d601d2fc5.map" but i assume it should be irrelevant.

Comment: I also tried to use cropit directly with some static html page, and it works just fine, so I assume the problem comes from that I didnt set everything well with Meteor @@

Comment: Generally saying running jquery plugins in `onCreated` callback is not the best idea. `onCreated` called when template instance gets initialised but before it gets rendered. So element `.image-editor` might not even exist at that moment yet. Instead you want to use `onRendered` callback that makes sure actual template's html got already rendered.

Answer (score 0):

you can used croper js file

file enter code here used cropper.js, cropper.min.js, cropper.css, cropper.min.css

```
<input id="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*" />  
<canvas id="canvas" height="5" width="5" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<img id="target" style="max-width: 100%" />

<button name="Save" value="Save" id="Save">Save</button>


  'change #file-upload' :function(e)
   { 

  encodeImageFileAsURL(); 
  function encodeImageFileAsURL() 
  {
    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("file-upload").files;
    if (filesSelected.length > 0) 
    {
      var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
        {

             $('#photos').hide();
             $('#crops').show();
             document.getElementById('target').src="";

             document.getElementById('target').src=fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
             $('#target').cropper(
             {
              aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
              minCropBoxWidth : 150,
              minCropBoxHeight :150,
              crop: function(e) 
              {

                // console.log(e.x);
                // console.log(e.y);
                // console.log(e.width);
                // console.log(e.height);
                // console.log(e.rotate);
                // console.log(e.scaleX);
                // console.log(e.scaleY);

                 $('#imgX1').val(e.x);
                 $('#imgY1').val(e.y);
                 $('#imgWidth').val(e.width);
                 $('#imgHeight').val(e.height);
                 $('#imgrotate').val(e.rotate);
                 $('#imgscaleX').val(e.scaleX);
                 $('#imgscaleY').val(e.scaleY);
              }
            });  
        }


    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);}}
     },
   'click #Save' : function(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var photoid = $('#photoid').val();
    var x1 = $('#imgX1').val();
    var y1 = $('#imgY1').val();
    var width = $('#imgWidth').val();
    var height = $('#imgHeight').val();
    var rotate = $('#imgrotate').val();
    var scaleX = $('#imgscaleX').val();
    var scaleY = $('#imgscaleY').val();

    var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = $('#target').attr("src");
    img.onload = function () `enter code here`
    {
       canvas.height = height;
       canvas.width = width;
       context.drawImage(img, x1, y1, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
       var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more explanation as to what you are doing here.